# Which Java Collection should I use?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, collections, hashmap

In this question [How can I efficiently select a Standard Library container in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11) is a handy flow chart to use when choosing C++ collections.

I thought that this was a useful resource for people who are not sure which collection they should be using so I tried to find a similar flow chart for Java and was not able to do so.

What resources and "cheat sheets" are available to help people choose the right Collection to use when programming in Java? How do people know what List, Set and Map implementations they should use?

Comment: The book Java Generics and Collections (Naftalin & Wadler) has a chapter about this.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here, but I did not see anything that talked about `Big-O`. Is not `Big-O` very useful to determine which `Collection` to use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations

Comment: @SedJ601 I don't go into it in detail but the consequences of BigO are covered in my explanation.

The order of an algorithm is not everything as it doesn't allow for the fixed costs. The cost overhead of LinkedList vs ArrayList is huge - so even for operations that are O(1) in linked lists and O(n) in ArrayList you need a very large list for one to overtake the other.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a similar flowchart I decided to make one myself.

This flow chart does not try and cover things like synchronized access, thread safety etc or the legacy collections, but it does cover the 3 standard **Set**s, 3 standard **Map**s and 2 standard **List**s.

[image]

<sub>This image was created for this answer and is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) The simplest attribution is by linking to either this question or this answer.</sub>

**Other resources**

Probably the most useful other reference is the following page from the oracle documentation which describes each [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html).

**HashSet vs TreeSet**

There is a detailed discussion of when to use `HashSet` or `TreeSet` here:
[Hashset vs Treeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463284/hashset-vs-treeset)

**ArrayList vs LinkedList**

Detailed discussion: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: Nice! But I must disagree with your `LinkedList` vs `ArrayList` decisions. First, if the list is of significant size, `LinkedList` is preferable. `LinkedList` has per-element overhead, so it is asymptotically worse in terms of memory consumption than an `ArrayList`. Also, if most of the access is at the end of the list, an `ArrayList` is preferable because it provides constant-time random element access. Accessing the `n`th element of a `LinkedList` is an `O(n)` operation. ...In fact, the decision to use a linked list should pretty much _always_ be "no."

Comment: @MattBall I agree with you for the most part. However Java `LinkedList` is a double linked list, so access at start and at end are both fast. You will note that of the branches above all three questions have to answer yes before I'd recommend using the `LinkedList` - so in other words I agree with you that in most cases the answer is no. Things like queues and dequeues where you are constantly adding and removing things from the ends of the list area good use-case for `LinkedList`.

Comment: @MattBall Memory usage is a much more tricky situation as while a `LinkedList` uses more memory per element...`ArrayList` never releases memory. That means that if you have a list that sometimes grows to a huge size but usually is small then an `ArrayList` will give worse memory performance. The memory overhead of the `List` itself is usually (although not always) small compared to that of the elements it contains as well.

Comment: `Map<K,V>` isn't the part of `java.util.collection`

Comment: @MehrajMalik Hmm, the labeling is ambiguous I agree. I meant Collection inside java.util. i.e. java.util.*insert collection name here*

Answer (score 84):

## Summary of the major non-concurrent, non-synchronized collections

[**`Collection`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html): An interface representing an unordered "bag" of items, called "elements". The "next" element is undefined (random).

- [**`Set`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html): An interface representing a `Collection` with no duplicates.

  - [**`HashSet`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): A `Set` backed by a [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Fastest and smallest memory usage, when ordering is unimportant.
  - [**`LinkedHashSet`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html): A `HashSet` with the addition of a linked list to associate elements in *insertion order*. The "next" element is the next-most-recently inserted element.
  - [**`TreeSet`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): A `Set` where elements are ordered by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (typically [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)). Slowest and largest memory usage, but necessary for comparator-based ordering.
  - [**`EnumSet`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html): An extremely fast and efficient `Set` customized for a single enum type.
- [**`List`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html): An interface representing a `Collection` whose elements are ordered and each have a numeric index representing its position, where zero is the first element, and `(length - 1)` is the last.

  - [**`ArrayList`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): A `List` backed by an array, where the array has a length (called "capacity") that is at least as large as the number of elements (the list's "size"). When size exceeds capacity (when the `(capacity + 1)-th` element is added), the array is recreated with a new capacity of `(new length * 1.5)`--this recreation is fast, since it uses [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)). Deleting and inserting/adding elements requires all neighboring elements (to the right) be shifted into or out of that space. Accessing any element is fast, as it only requires the calculation `(element-zero-address + desired-index * element-size)` to find it's location. [In most situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist), an `ArrayList` is preferred over a `LinkedList`.
  - [**`LinkedList`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): A `List` backed by a set of objects, each linked to its "previous" and "next" neighbors. A `LinkedList` is also a `Queue` and `Deque`. Accessing elements is done starting at the first or last element, and traversing until the desired index is reached. Insertion and deletion, *once the desired index is reached via traversal* is a trivial matter of re-mapping only the immediate-neighbor links to point to the new element or bypass the now-deleted element.
- [**`Map`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html): An interface representing an `Collection` where each element has an identifying "key"--each element is a key-value pair.

  - [**`HashMap`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): A `Map` where keys are unordered, and backed by a `Hashtable`.
  - [**`LinkedhashMap`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedhashMap.html): Keys are ordered by *insertion order*.
  - [**`TreeMap`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): A `Map` where keys are ordered by a `Comparator` (typically natural ordering).
- [**`Queue`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html): An interface that represents a `Collection` where elements are, typically, added to one end, and removed from the other (FIFO: first-in, first-out).
- [**`Stack`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html): An interface that represents a `Collection` where elements are, typically, both added (pushed) and removed (popped) from the same end (LIFO: last-in, first-out).
- [**`Deque`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html): Short for "double ended queue", usually pronounced "deck". A linked list that is typically only added to and read from either end (not the middle).

Basic collection diagrams:

[image: diagram]

Comparing the insertion of an element with an `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`:

[image: diagram]

Comment: Best in brief summery that one can get anywhere :)

Answer (score 14):

Even simpler picture is here. Intentionally simplified!

1. **[Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html)** is anything holding data called "elements" (of the same type). Nothing more specific is assumed.
2. **[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)** is an *indexed* collection of data where each element has an index. Something like the array, but more flexible.

   Data in the list keep the order of insertion.

   Typical operation: get the n-th element.
3. **[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)** is a *bag of elements*, each elements just once (the elements are distinguished using their `equals()` method.

   Data in the set are stored mostly just to know *what* data are there.

   Typical operation: tell if an element is present in the list.
4. **[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)** is something like the List, but instead of accessing the elements by their integer index, you access them by their *key*, which is any object. Like the array in PHP :)

   Data in Map are searchable by their key.

   Typical operation: get an element by its ID (where ID is of any type, not only `int` as in case of List).

#### The differences

- Set vs. Map: in Set you *search* data *by themselves*, whilst in Map *by their key*.

  N.B. The standard library Sets are indeed implemented exactly like this: a map where the keys are the Set elements themselves, and with a dummy value.
- List vs. Map: in List you access elements by their `int` index (position in List), whilst in Map by their key which os of any type (typically: ID)
- List vs. Set: in List the elements are bound by their position and can be duplicate, whilst in Set the elements are just "present" (or not present) and are unique (in the meaning of `equals()`, or `compareTo()` for [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html))

Answer (score 3):

## Map

If choosing a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), I made this table summarizing the features of each of the ten implementations bundled with Java 11.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Answer (score 2):

It is simple: if you need to store values with keys mapped to them go for the Map interface, otherwise use List for values which may be duplicated and finally use the Set interface if you don’t want duplicated values in your collection.

Here is the complete explanation http://javatutorial.net/choose-the-right-java-collection , including flowchart etc

Answer (score 0):

Common collections, Common collections
[image]

Comment: [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is not an interface.