# What is the best way to build a set of objects of dynamic length in java?

Tags: java, set

Let's suppose my Java program has 3 types of custom designed objects (entities, relationships, rulesets).  If I need to build a collection of at least 1, but up to 3 of the types, each with a size of 0 to n, what is the best way to do so?  Is the set class the right thing to use?  Can the Collection class be used?  How would I define such a 'set' or 'collection' in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use

Comment: That's a good page!  My googlefoo failed me, hence why I wrote this.  I think I can figure it out from here.  Should I close this?

Comment: Not sure. Great chart, though, right?

Comment: I tried to close this but I could not.  If you make this the answer I'll award you credit for doing so.

Comment: Done. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This flow chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use), as created by @[TimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049628/tim-b), is a great tool for determining the right collection based on particular requirements.

[image]