# Built in method for removing duplicates in a string array

Tags: java, duplicates

Is there a java built-in method for removing duplicates ? (`array of strings`)

Maybe using a `Set` ? in this case how can I use it ?

Thanks

Comment: how ? say my array is a. how do I create the set ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array of string, you can directly use a `set` (in this case all elements in set will always be unique of that type) but if you only want to use `array of strings` , you can use the following to save `array` to `set` then save it back.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        String dupArray[] = {"hi","hello","hi"};
        dupArray=removeDuplicates(dupArray);

        for(String s: dupArray)
                 System.out.println(s);
     }

    public static String[] removeDuplicates(String []dupArray)
    {
        HashSet<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(dupArray));
        dupArray = new String[mySet.size()];
        mySet.toArray(dupArray);
        return dupArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge hashset, does not guarantee an order , why not try LinkedHashSet ?

Comment: OP did not mention ordering is required